# Have you had success with 2D graphics via HTML canvas?

Tags: graphics, canvas

I'm looking for success and failure stories of web applications rendering rich, 2D graphics via the HTML canvas element. I've seen some intriguing examples online but wanted to learn about some real-world, practical examples of development done using this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly a what you are looking for but [GWT-canvas](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-canvas/) is worth of checking. At least it is a HTML Canvas project.

Answer (score 0):

For me the kicker is text.  I need to render vector graphics **AND** text.

Thus I prefer SVG.

That said, for simple graphics, even complex ones, CANVAS is a great tool.

Answer (score 0):

I had a grading application that used the canvas tag. The instructor could set the new curve for grades and I would display a histogram of how many students would get each grade, based on the change.

This way the instructor could easily see if the curve met their expectations, so they could get the shape they wanted.

I also used the canvas tag as a way to design images that later may be turned into a real bitmapped image, so I could easily experiment and decide which image would work best, based on feedback from users.  It is quicker for me to make changes with the canvas tag than to get a bitmapped image to be the correct size and look.